# Somewhat Infinite Output in Python

Tags: python, infinite-loop

I have written Python code where I tried to contain all the possible combinations of words with or without meaning but it seems to be somewhat infinite [although it has limits]. I mean, using the letters abcd...wxyz to construct those possible words leading to 10 billion+ results. Is it possible to run this kind of code where you'll be having the expected output after some time? I have manage to make my own code but it makes my PC slower temporarily so I decided to terminate it before it totally crashes my OS.

Comment: What does your code look like, and what is the expected output?  It's difficult to determine what, if any, effects there will be without seeing the code.  "What have you tried?" and "What have you found out?" are too good things to include when asking a question.  It's unlikely that it will crash your system, though you may hit a memory constraint at some point, if you're storing all the results.

Comment: best would be to show your code or to explain what you mean with `try to contain`?

Creating a list with all these words will probably exceed your memory, but creating a generator, that displays all of these words or tries to do something with these words is definitely possible.

Comment: "Somewhat infinite" ?

Answer (score 0):

Using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) will get you what you want, and you can cycle through the many, MANY combinations at whatever speed you want. Here's an example of how to generate all the combinations efficiently:

```
import itertools
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
length = 5
alphabets = [alphabet] * length
combos_generator = itertools.product(*alphabets)
print(len(list(combos_generator)))
```

Note that the number of combinations will be 26 ^ num_letters, or in this case, over 11million combinations for just 5-letter words (aaaaa through zzzzz). If you actually want to access them efficiently, use the interator-style access:

```
for combo in combos_generator:
    <do something, output to file, etc>
    ...
```

Happy Coding!